# Replace ID in a URL between two markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a url which looks like this:

```
<a href="http://url/images/1034749-184e-3467-87e0-d7546df59896?w=600&amp;r=22036"></a>
```

I want to replace: `1034749-184e-3467-87e0-d7546df59896` with another ID, is there any regex or similar replace method which will allow me to replace the ID using JavaScript between the '`image/`' and '`?`' characters?

Comment: The ID is always unique so I can't match on the contents of the ID string.

Comment: are the ids always the same length?

Comment: Afraid not the ID can be variable in length.

Comment: @CLiown, If can go by the number of "/"s before and get the location of the "/" before what you need. You can then get the location of the "?" and do some string manipulation to get you what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make this approximation expression:

```
/[0-9a-z]+(?:-[0-9a-z]+){4}/i
```

Match a bunch of hexadecimals, followed by 4 sections, each starting with a dash followed by a bunch of hexadecimals.

```
> var s = 'http://url/images/1034749-184e-3467-87e0-d7546df59896?w=600&amp;r=22036';
> console.log(s.replace(/[0-9a-z]+(?:-[0-9a-z]+){4}/i, 'something-else'));

http://url/images/something-else?w=600&amp;r=22036
```

Answer (score 3):

`/images\/[^?]+/` would match, but it would replace `images/` as well.

Fortunately you can pass a callback to [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
url.replace(/(images\/)[^?]+/, function($match, $1) {
    // results in "images/<some-ID>" 
    return $1 + theNewId;
});
```

---

If you have a reference to the DOM element anyway, you can also just replace the last step of the path:

```
element.pathname = 
  element.pathname.substring(0, element.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + newId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just do this:

```
var url = document.getElementById("yoururlid").src;
url = url.split("/");
var newUrl = url[0] + url[1] + url[2] + url[3] + newURLID;
```

Why not just do this:

```
document.getElementById("yoururlid").src="http://url/images/" + newId + "?w=600&amp;r=22036";
```

Comment: `.split` returns an array, so you'd have to do `url = url.split("/")`. But how you adding what comes after the old ID (`?=...`)?

Comment: My bad, I missed that. I don't know why he doesn't just change the src like this: src = "firstPart" + newId + "lastpart";